# If two functions are in arithmetic operations in recursion, which function will work first?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int count(int S[], int m, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (m <= 0 && n >= 1)
        return 0;

    return count(S, m - 1, n) + count(S, m, n - S[m - 1]);
}
```

Does it end with `count(S, m - 1, n)` and then start with the next `count(S, m, n - S[m - 1])`? Or do two have to be calculators from both sides at the same time? Will there be any value change of `count(S, m, n - S[m - 1])` for `count(S, m - 1, n)`?

Here is my full [code](https://onlinegdb.com/QUuurslK3)

Comment: @VLAZ this is C++

Comment: _"...Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again...."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @VLAZ In older versions of C++ there were sequence points that had to be done in order. In your example the `;` is a sequence point so those two operations will be done in order. But `+` is not a sequence point so either function call on that line can be done in any order - and the CPU can reorder it to keep the pipeline full so it might not always be done in the same order. They got rid of sequence points in the most recent C++ Standard but the replacement is just as "unspecified" That clause in the Standard is intentional just so that the CPU can reorder operations to keep the pipeline full.

Comment: @VLAZ The issue here is the evaluation order of subexpressions. And in your example, the initializations *could* occur in any order, since there is no observable difference.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah -- it's also there so that the **compiler** can reorder operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

in

```
return count(S, m - 1, n) + count(S, m, n - S[m - 1]);
```

we just have the guaranty that:

- `S`, `m-1` (first one) and `n` are computed before `count(S, m - 1, n)`
- `m-1` (second one) is computed before `S[m - 1]`
- `S[m - 1]` is computed before `n - S[m - 1]`
- `S`, `m`, and `n - S[m - 1]` are computed before `count(S, m, n - S[m - 1])`

in particular

`count(S, m - 1, n)` can be computed before or after `count(S, m, n - S[m - 1])` (and that for any call) (and they cannot "overlap", one is computed before the other).

Fortunately, `count` doesn't have side effects or change their arguments, so any order is correct in your cases.

Comment: In addition, the OP asked whether the two recursive calls could be computed *at the same time*. The answer is a hard no: the left one can be computed before or after the right one; but it will definitely be one first then the other second, not both at the same time. I think you assumed this was too obvious to include it in your answer, but given the OP's question, it's not obvious to them.